# Ran "chmod 777" in ADB, now I can't execute my app from Eclipse any more

Tags: android, eclipse, shell, adb, chmod

I needed to edit the shared preferences XML file of my app, so I used the File Explorer in Eclipse to pull it, edited it, and pushed it back to the phone.

In order to access the data folder I had to run "su" and "chmod 777" in the ADB Shell first. I was lazy and ran "chmod 777 /data/data/com.abcdefgh.project/*/*" to make all the files and folders of my app accessible.

The problem is, now I can't run my app from Eclipse anymore! Here's an excerpt from the LogCat:

```
03-20 21:25:55.225: E/ApplicationContext(15838): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file /data/data/com.abcdefgh.project/shared_prefs/com.abcdefgh.project_preferences.xml

03-20 21:25:55.415: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(15838): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
```

How do I get it back to normal again? Do I need to chmod everything back to the original state? If that's the case, what IS the original state, and why doesn't "777" work?

Comment: 777 is a very bad choice, but your problem is likely not that, but that in pushing the replacement you left something owned by adb's `shell` user which the app cannot clean up.  Either go in and remove that file, chown it back to the app userid, or see if you can clear that app's data from settings, uninstall the app, or rm -rf the the app's entire private directory.

Comment: `I needed to edit the shared preferences XML file of my app` - I'm curious - why?  Why not just do it in code?

Comment: How do I get it back to normal again? - Uninstalling and reinstalling the application should get you back to the original state.

Comment: @Simon I needed to have a look at the preferences from an older version of my app, and copy some of values to the development version to simulate an update from an old version to a new one. Of course I could have done it in code, but I was both lazy and curious about how they are stored :) Won't be doing that again! I ended up uninstalling the app and reinstalling, will have to programmatically simulate an update I guess.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks, I guess your comment explains everything. If you care to make an answer I will accept it!